# Can't start bounty on mobile?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mobile-web

On mobile (iOS, Chrome) it seems like the "start a bounty" label does not appear..?

I check under the "add comment" but there's nothing like "question eligible for bounty in 1 hour" or "start a bounty".

This seems to have with the CSS style sheet for mobile or something to do.

EDIT:

[image: Stackoverflow]

I'm using iPod Touch 4G

Comment: Can't repro, mobile theme does contain the link. You sure that in the full site view you do see the link? On what question is this?

Comment: And to prove my point, [screenshot of a random question with the link in there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wi4jF.png) (taken in iPhone 4S, iOS 7, native Safari browser)

Comment: You can't start a bounty for 2 days after first asking a question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189824/why-doesnt-the-mobile-site-tell-us-how-long-we-have-to-wait-to-add-a-bounty

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with the mobile theme, everything to do with when the question was asked.

You cannot offer a bounty for the first two days of asking a question.

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

Comment: Which means I can't see the "question eligible for bounty in 1 hour" only?

Comment: Not sure that shows up at all. It doesn't show up on the main site either.

Comment: Yes it does on the main site..

Comment: OK. That's the bug then. Not sure that bit has been ported to the mobile site.